# Hamburger menu not showing on iOS . Prism issue, Xamarin issue or my issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, prism, hamburger-menu

I am trying to implement a masterDetail app with hamburger menu.
It works in android but crashes on iOS with "FileNotFoundException" and shows default instead the icon.

I have added an icon to iOS. Resources project but still does not show and both the master and navigation page have the icon.

Am I doing something wrong?
Any workaround?
thanks a lot

app.xaml

```
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainMasterDetail/MyNavigationPage/MainPage",animated:false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }           
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes()
        {
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainMasterDetail,MainMasterDetailViewModel>();
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MyNavigationPage,MyNavigationPageViewModel>();
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA,ViewAViewModel>();
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewB,ViewBViewModel>();

        }
    }
```

MainMasterDetails.xaml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                          xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                          prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                          x:Class="HelloBurgerMenu.Views.MainMasterDetail"
                          Title="MainMasterDetail" Icon="humburger.png">
            <MasterDetailPage.Master>
                <ContentPage Title="Default">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Button Text="MainPage" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="MyNavigationPage/MainPage" />
                        <Button Text="ViewA" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="MyNavigationPage/ViewA" />
                        <Button Text="ViewB" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="MyNavigationPage/ViewB" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ContentPage>
            </MasterDetailPage.Master>

        </MasterDetailPage>


MyNavigationPage

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <NavigationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                    x:Class="HelloBurgerMenu.Views.MyNavigationPage"
                    Icon="humburger.png">

    </NavigationPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have content in your NavigationPage.  Delete all the XAML in your NavigationPage.

Look at this sample: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/MasterDetailPage

Comment: Hi thanks but that was a copy and paste mistake.that is empty. By setting the icon on the content page it shows even thought it crashes with "filenotfound" but icon is there. Is it supposed to show the back arrow withtitle instead of Hamburger.png when navigating forward?

Comment: If you remove the hamburger icon, does it work?  If so, you know what the issue it..

Comment: You don't add the hamburger icon to the navigation page, you add it to the master.

Answer (score 1):

Try specify the Icon in MasterPage not MasterDetail

```
 public MasterPage()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
    {
       Icon = "menu.png";
    } 
 }
```

Comment: "Icon is obsolete as of 4.0.0. Please use IconImageSource instead."